# create process in user session from service

Tags: windows, winapi, service

i am trying to make a service create a process in opened session in windows.
i have this code:

```
    sessionId =WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
if (WTSQueryUserToken(sessionId,&dummy)) {
    if (!DuplicateTokenEx(dummy, TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, SecurityDelegation, TokenPrimary, &token)) {
        CloseHandle(dummy);
        return false;
    }
    CloseHandle(dummy);
    // Create process for user with desktop
    myfile = fopen("c:\\temp\\test123.txt", "a");
    fprintf(myfile, "before create!!!!\n");
    fclose(myfile);
    if (!CreateProcessAsUser(token, NULL,NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {  // The "new console" is necessary. Otherwise the process can hang our main process
        CloseHandle(token);
        myfile = fopen("c:\\temp\\test123.txt", "a");
        fprintf(myfile, " create failed!\n");
        fclose(myfile);
        return false;
    }
    CloseHandle(token);
}
else {
    myfile = fopen("c:\\temp\\test123.txt", "a");
    fprintf(myfile, "Dummy fail\n");
    fprintf(myfile, "last error is %d \n", GetLastError());
    fclose(myfile);
}
//int ret = CreateProcess(FILE_EXEC, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

if i use the last lin e(that commented) in the install of the service all works fine because it runs when the service is been installed so it happens inside the User session but when i want the service to do it it fails, sessionId is ok, the failure starts at :

```
    if (WTSQueryUserToken(sessionId,&dummy)) {
```

i know that WTSQueryUserToken is a function that should be run from service, sessionid is 1 (and it is the real number from cmd check) and the dummy is suppose to hold the user token after it but for some reason it fails.... any ideas?

Comment: And the error number is?  Note that your call to `GetLastError` will return nonsense because you call it long after the function that failed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use code similar to yours in my own service and it works fine.  There are some things that need to be taken into account that the code you showed is not doing:

1. When calling `WTSQueryUserToken()`, you have to make sure your service process has the `SE_TCB_NAME` privilege enabled.  Use `AdjustTokenPrivileges()` for that.
2. The session ID returned by `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()` **may not** be the correct session that you need to run your spawned process on! It returns the session ID that is attached to the **physical console** (screen/keyboard/mouse) of the local machine, if any. That session may be displaying the secure WinLogon desktop, meaning no user is actually logged in to the physical machine, so calling `WTSQueryUserToken()` on that session ID would fail with an `ERROR_NO_TOKEN` error. A user can log in over a Remote Desktop Connection, for instance, in which case that connection would be running in a different session than the console. If you want your spawned process to run in a session that has a user logged in, you need to use `WTSEnumerateSessions()` to find a session that is in the `WTSActive` state.  And even then, `WTSQueryUserToken()` may not return a token depending on how the user is logged in, so you need to call `WTSQueryUserToken()` on each active session you find until you find one that successfully gives you a token.
3. When calling `DuplicateTokenEx()`, use `SecurityIdentification` instead of `SecurityDelegation`.
4. When calling `CreateProcessAsUser()`, you can call `CreateEnvironmentBlock()` first to create an environment that is appropriate for that specific user and then pass that pointer to `CreateProcessAsUser()`.  Otherwise, the spawned process will use your service's environment instead. This step is optional, depending on the particular needs of the spawned app.

Comment: Is it necessary to duplicate the token at all?  The documentation seems to imply that WTSQueryUserToken returns a primary token, so I'd have expected to be able to use it directly in the call to CreateProcessAsUser.

Comment: According to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/37453c4d-3208-40b2-9efd-d7fbe8e2edfd/is-duplicatetokenex-mandatory-with-createprocessasuser-function?forum=windowssdk), it is not necessary, but I never tried it to verify. There are tons of examples floating around that use `DuplicateTokenEx()` with `WTSQueryUserToken()` when calling `CreateProcessAsUser()`.  Maybe it was a requirement in older OS versions and is no longer necessary? I do not know.

Comment: first thanks, i am using CreateProcessAsUser(token,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,FALSE,NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,NULL,NULL,$si,&pi) and i get error 183, any idea what else i can do?

Comment: Error 183 is `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`, which is not an error code that `CreateProcessAsUser()` should be reporting. You are probably not managing your error handling correctly, such as if you are calling `GetLastError()` at the wrong time and seeing an error from another system function instead of `CreateProcessAsUser()`.

Comment: you right, but any idea why CreateProcessAsUser fails??

Comment: Not without seeing the true error code that it actually reports.

Answer (score 2):

The code is correct....make sure that you include  ***"wtsapi.h"*** header file and this "***#pragma comment(lib, "WtsApi32.lib")***",because it is important to load the dll,else you will get linking error(*error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol*).
And also duplicating token  is not necessary...and privileges setting is not required because when the process is called from  the  service in your user account..the default session id will be 0 i.e,. SYSTEM account..which has all the privileges which a user can have...

my code works properly when process is called from a service:

```
   LPCWSTR path=L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe";//change the path accordingly

     PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
        STARTUPINFO si;
         DWORD nsid=1;

          ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
          si.cb = sizeof( si );
          HANDLE htoken;

          DWORD sessionId;

         sessionId =WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
         WTSQueryUserToken(sessionId,&htoken);
         si.wShowWindow=TRUE;
         if (CreateProcessAsUser(htoken, path, NULL, NULL,
                      NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi ))
          {
             /* Process has been created; work with the process and wait for it to
             terminate. */
                WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
               CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
                 CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
           }

         CloseHandle(htoken);
```

for clear idea about service refer [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/499465/Simple-Windows-Service-in-Cplusplus) .Download the source code and the code is perfect.
Just insert this piece of code in the 'ServiceWorkerThread' function.this piece of code is for opening an .exe (Eg.File Explorer,Notepad,etc.,) file from your service.The .exe file will open when you start your service from services.msc( windows application).