# How to start a foreground process even if its parent is a Windows service or daemon process?

Tags: windows, service, robotframework, foreground

I have a parent process which stared as a service. This service needs to start RobotFramework.

If Robotframework did not start foreground, Selenium test library will complain when starting the browser (Chrome) and fail.

for example, i have a testcase like:
test.txt

```
***setting***
Library SeleniumLibrary

***test case***
open_browser
   Open Browser    www.stackflow.com  chrome
```

i run test.txt from a windows service process, by invoke command like

```
pybot test.txt
```

since pybot`s parent is a service ,so, pybot also become a backgroud process, and this result selenum complain open brower failed

What should I do to make RobotFramework start on the foreground? Or is there another way to make Selenium work properly?

Comment: Adding more clarity to your question will improve your chances of getting a good answer...

Comment: possible duplicate of [create process in user session from service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913172/create-process-in-user-session-from-service)