# Service Application in Delphi do not Open an Exe file on desktop?

Tags: delphi, service, desktop

I am using a `Service Application` in `Delphi`. This is my code in `ServiceExecute` method

```
procedure TMDPSERVICE.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
const
  SecBetweenRuns = 10;
var
  Count: Integer;
begin
  while not Terminated do // loop around until we should stop
  begin
    Inc(Count);
    if Count >= SecBetweenRuns then
    begin
      if not DoFindTask('c:\weblod.exe') then 
        WinExec(PAnsiChar('c:\weblod.exe'), SW_NORMAL);
    end;
    Sleep(10);
  end;
end;
```

I can see `weblod.exe` file on taskmanager but it is not showing on Desktop?

Comment: Windows Services as of Windows Vista run in Session 0. All spawned processes do the same. These have no interaction with the user.

Answer (score 3):

Services run in an isolated session, session 0. Interactive desktops are always in different sessions. Read about session 0 isolation to learn more.

If you want to launch the process on an interactive desktop you need something like this: [create process in user session from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913172/create-process-in-user-session-from-service)

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, you are misusing the `TService.OnExecute` event.  Specifically, you are never calling `ServiceThread.ProcessRequests()` so your service can respond to SCM requests.  At the very least, you must add that to your loop:

```
procedure TMDPSERVICE.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
const
  SecBetweenRuns = 10;
var
  Count: Integer;
begin
  while not Terminated do // loop around until we should stop
  begin
    Inc(Count);
    if Count >= SecBetweenRuns then
    begin
      if not DoFindTask('c:\weblod.exe') then 
        WinExec(PAnsiChar('c:\weblod.exe'), SW_NORMAL);
    end;
    Sleep(10);
    ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(False); // <-- add this
  end;
end;
```

A better (and preferred) option is to not use the `OnExecute` event at all.  `TService` automatically processes SCM requests when no `OnExecute` handler is assigned.  You should use the `TService.OnStart` event to start a worker thread, and use the `TService.OnStop`/`TService.OnShutdown` events to terminate that thread:

```
type
  TMyTaskThread = class(TThread)
  protected 
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

procedure TMyTaskThread.Execute;
const
  SecBetweenRuns = 10;
var
  Count: Integer;
begin
  while not Terminated do // loop around until we should stop
  begin
    Inc(Count);
    if Count >= SecBetweenRuns then
    begin
      if not DoFindTask('c:\weblod.exe') then 
        WinExec(PAnsiChar('c:\weblod.exe'), SW_NORMAL);
    end;
    Sleep(10);
  end;
end;
```

```
type
  TMDPSERVICE = class(TService)
    procedure ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
    procedure ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
    procedure ServiceShutdown(Sender: TService);
  private
    FTask: TMyTaskThread;
  end;

procedure TMDPSERVICE.ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
begin
  FTask := TMyTaskThread.Create(False);
  Started := True;
end;

procedure TMDPSERVICE.ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
begin
  ServiceShutdown(Sender);
  Stopped := True;
end;

procedure TMDPSERVICE.ServiceShutdown(Sender: TService);
begin
  if Assigned(FTask) then
  begin
    FTask.Terminate;
    while WaitForSingleObject(FTask.Handle, WaitHint-100) = WAIT_TIMEOUT do
      ReportStatus;
    FreeAndNil(FTask);
  end;
end;
```

Now, with that said, `WinExec()` has been deprecated since Windows 95 was first introduced.  Don't use `WinExec()` at all, especially from a service.  You need to use `CreateProcessAsUser()` instead.  Not only does that allow you to specify which desktop to run the process on, it also allows you to specify which user session the process runs in.  This is especially important in Windows Vista and later due to *Session 0 Isolation*, because logged-in users do not run in the same session as services anymore (which is also why the `TService.Interactive` property is no longer supported, either).  If you don't specify a user session, the process would run in the same session as the service, and as the same user that the service is running as (which is usually `SYSTEM`).  A logged-in user will never see the process.

Try something more like this:

```
function WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId: DWORD; stdcall; external 'Wtsapi32.dll';
function WTSQueryUserToken(SessionId: ULONG; var phToken: THandle): BOOL; stdcall; external 'Wtsapi32.dll';

function CreateEnvironmentBlock(var lpEnvironment: Pointer; hToken: THandle; bInherit: BOOL): BOOL; stdcall; external 'Userenv.dll';
function DestroyEnvironmentBlock(lpEnvironment: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall; external 'Userenv.dll';

function RunTaskOnUserDesktop(CmdLine: string): Boolean;
var
  hToken: THandle;
  env: Pointer;
  si: STARTUPINFO;
  pi: PROCESS_INFORMATION;
begin
  Result := False;
  // WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId() returns the ID of the user session that is
  // logged in to the physical console (keyboard/mouse/screen). If remote users
  // can login to your machine, and you want to run your process in a remote
  // user's session, use WTSEnumerateSessions() instead to find the ID of the
  // desired logged-in user session...
  //
  if not WTSQueryUserToken(WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(), hToken) then
    Exit;
  try
    if not CreateEnvironmentBlock(env, hToken, False) then
      Exit;
    try
      ZeroMemory(@si, SizeOf(si));
      si.cb := SizeOf(si);
      si.lpDesktop := 'Winsta0\Default';
      si.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
      si.wShowWindow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
      Result := CreateProcessAsUser(hToken, nil, PChar(CmdLine), nil, nil, False, CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, env, nil, si, pi);
      if Result then
      begin
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
      end;
    finally
      DestroyEnvironmentBlock(env);
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(hToken);
  end;
end;

...

const
  SecBetweenRuns = 10;
var
  Count: Integer;
begin
  while not Terminated do // loop around until we should stop
  begin
    Inc(Count);
    if Count >= SecBetweenRuns then
    begin
      if not DoFindTask('c:\weblod.exe') then 
        RunTaskOnUserDesktop('c:\weblod.exe');
    end;
    Sleep(10);
  end;
end;
```