# Get URL Of Current Internet Explorer Web Page from service

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, visual-c++, service, msdn

I'm trying to extract the URLs Of Current Internet Explorer Web Pages from service.
I tried using CLSID_ShellWindows with the following code:

```
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellWindows, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IShellWindows, (void **)& pIShellWindows);
long count;
pIShellWindows->get_Count(&count);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    VARIANT vt;
    VariantInit(&vt);
    vt.vt = VT_I4;
    vt.lVal = i;
    hr = pIShellWindows->Item(vt, &pIDispatch);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && (pIDispatch != NULL))
    {
        // "Dispatch success"         
        IWebBrowser2 *tab = NULL;
        hr = pIDispatch->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowser2, (void **)&tab); 
        BSTR bstr;
        tab->get_LocationURL(&bstr);
     }
}
```

The code works from user app (Non-service). That's probably because that the service and the user apps runs in different sessions (LocalSystem).

I tried to impersonate to the logged on user using ImpersonateLoggedOnUser but that didn't work.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: I think this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913172/create-process-in-user-session-from-service, if you create a user process from the service, this user process will allow to retrieve the URL, in future please write where it fails in case you say that it doesn't work.