# Access all AppData from Windows Service as Local System

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, wcf, windows-services

I'm trying to develop an application that is composed by two parts, a Windows Service and a WPF GUI to manage the data used by the Service.

The Windows Service is running under Local System profile, and the UI part is installed for all users. This UI stores the data used by the Service on the AppData folder, so I need to retrieve the path to the folder for each user from the service to everything work fine.

The other solution is to have the data stored in the Program Files folder, but this way, all users can see the config and data from other users and the Application must run under Administrative privileges to write to C:/Program Files.

Finally the third solution, and the one that I'm currently using, is to have the Windows Service to host a WCF to commuinicate the GUI with the Service, so this last one is the only one who is able to write to C:/Program Files, and the UI does not require Administrative rights.

Which is the best sollution for me?

BTW: right now my data is stored in encrypted json format in txt files, but this is another querstion here.

**EDIT:** This brings to my head another question. How do big applications write to their own ProgramFile folder? Like aniviruses and this kind of giant apps.

Comment: This is a really opinion based question and the answer bases on your needs. So hard to say. If using WCF works, so why change a running system?

Comment: Because WCF is too complex for a very simple program as mine. And all users can access others data.

Comment: If the only problem is determining the path for each user's AppData folder, can't the UI part just tell the Windows Service what the corresponding path is?  (As to your last question: writable data is usually stored in ProgramData rather than Program Files.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston yes, it might be a possible solution, but where should the Windows Service store the paths strings? And, do the Antiviruses store the data on the User folders? Don't they store data on System level?

Comment: ProgramData is a global folder, not a per-user folder.  And the Windows Service shouldn't need to store the path strings at all; the UI component will be running for each logged-on user, won't it?  So the service can just query the UI component on the fly.

Comment: @HarryJohnston how can you query the UI component? I have a similar situation where I need to get the appData location from a windows service

Comment: @SZaman, whatever IPC mechanism you're most comfortable with.  If you're starting from scratch, I'd suggest [a mailslot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365576(v=vs.85).aspx) as the simplest option.  If you don't already have a component running in the user's context, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26915687/886887) - and many more, just search Stack Overflow for WTSQueryUserToken.