# Windows Share Drives not getting complete list in GetLogicalDriveStrings() using C Windows API

Tags: c, winapi

Not able to get complete share drive information from **GetLogicalDriveStrings (in Production code)** while using C Windows API, but it works fine with sample program in same machine.

For these function any extra access privilege or Environment setting required ?

**Environment Details:**

Windows Server 2012 R2  (2 Machine connected in same network)

Production code compiled with Visual Studio 2017 SDK.

**Reproducible Steps:**

***Machine 1: Windows Server 2012 R2:***
Created Folder (MICRO_TEST) -> RIght Click "Share With"  -> "Specific People" -> Selected "Everyone" -> ADD -> Permission Level "Read/Write" -> Share -> Done

Copied Network Share Path from folder properties (Sharing tab): 
\\SYSTEM_HOSTNAME\micro_test

***Machine 2: Windows Server 2012 R2:*** 
This PC -> Manage Tab -> Map Network Drive -> Map Network Drive -> Drive (U:) -> Folder (\\SYSTEM_HOSTNAME\micro_test) -> Browse -> Selected (MICRO_TEST) -> Ok -> Enabled "Reconnect at sign-in" -> Finish.

File System in Drive Properties: NTFS

***Executed program Machine 2 :***
Identified all local drives ( A:, C: and D: ) except MICRO_TEST share drive letter (U:)

***Snippet Code:***

```
    char buff [8192];
    if (!GetLogicalDriveStrings (sizeof(buff)-1, buff)) {
        printf("GetLogicalDriveStrings failed %d", GetLastError());
        return (NULL);
    }

    char *charPtr = buff;
    while (*charPtr ) {            
        printf ("Drive Letter: %s", charPtr);
        charPtr += strlen(charPtr) + 1;
    }
```

Comment: Did you mean SMB 3.0 protocol? According to the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getlogicaldrivestringsw#remarks): `GetLogicalDriveStrings` is not supported by the SMB 3.0 protocol in Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Thanks for information Drake, New to windows environment. But it is working properly with sample program.

Comment: Do you mean if file shared by the machine 2, then machine 1 can get the driver?

Comment: Also please check this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3035277/mapped-drives-are-not-available-from-an-elevated-prompt-when-uac-is-co), and try to set `EnableLinkedConnections`.

Comment: I figured out that my app is running as service in session 0(super user) and starts whenever the system started. But LogicaldriveString is not returning those disks which are shared by other system on "sessions"  with administrator user. Now i want to monitor all those disks as well which are created in "sessions"

Comment: How we can acheive ?, We are doing search along with ImpersonateLoggedOnUser and CreateProcessAsUser but did not reach to any conclusion yet . Any sample program from where we can get the reference ?

Comment: I will consult with relevant internal engineers to find out if there is any way to achieve this, and update here.

Comment: From engineer: "This is expected since session 0 is special for Windows. You need to access the Windows Shared Driver in a logon session"

Comment: You could try the sample as this case: [create process in user session from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913172/create-process-in-user-session-from-service)