# Launch Interactive App From Windows Service in Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, impersonation, user-permissions

I'm running a Windows Service in a Windows 10 machine logged with a low privileges User, I'm trying to launch an interactive application (ex. notepad) in the context of the logged user.

The windows service is running with the admin credentials

[image]

I use the next code inside my service.

```
   [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
   private static extern uint WaitForSingleObject(IntPtr handle, uint milliseconds);

   var startupInfo = new StartupInfo();         // StartupInfo struct
   var processInfo = new ProcessInformation();  // ProcessInfo struct

   // COMMAND TO EXECUTE
   const string command = "cmd.exe /C c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe";

   var response = CreateProcessWithLogonW(
                    "adminUserName", //user
                    ".",             //domain
                    "adminUserPwd",  //password
                    (uint)0,         //logonFlags
                    null,            //appName
                    command,         //command
                    (uint)0,         //creationFlags
                    (uint)0,         //environment
                    null,            //currentDirectory
                    ref startupInfo,
                    out processInfo);

   if (!response)
   {
       Log($"Error: {Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()}");
       return false;
   }

   const uint infinite = 0xFFFFFFFF;
   const uint waitFailed = 0xFFFFFFFF;

   var uiResultWait = WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.process, infinite);
   
   if (uiResultWait == waitFailed)
   {
       Log($"Error: {Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()}");
       return false;
   }

   return true;
```

The function responses successfully and I can see the notepad running too, but not appears the window (seems like running in another user context)

[image]

Someone can tell me what i'm missing?

Best regards

Comment: Services run in Session 0, a non-interactive user session. That's where your Notepad process lives.

Comment: Thank's for the answer, I understand that the process that was run through the windows service is created in Session 0 which is non-interactive session, what I need to do for achieve the app running in an interactive context?

Comment: Probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26913172/1889329).