# How to open notepad when from application that starts as schedule task when user is not log on?

Tags: c#

I have a gRPC service that is hosted in a ASP application.

I create a task scehdule that is starts no matter if the user log on or not. This user is user A.

I have test that the application works when the computer starts, because it has a method to say "hello" to check if it is running or not.

I have created another method in the gRPC service to open the notepad for testing.

When I log on with the user A, I try to open the notepad, but this doesn't work.

I have tried to run the ASP application manually, so I can see the log windows, and in this case the notepad is opened.

Also I have tried to run the application as scheduled task, in this case when user log on, and it work too. Really it is the same that if I run it manually, I see the log windows.

So I guess the problem is related when I start the application as scheduled task without the need the user has to log on.

The reason to use a scheduled task no matter if the user log on or not it is because I don't want to see the log windows of the ASP application, so it is running in the backgruound and it doesn't dusturb.

So my question is, how could I run the ASP application without showing the window and can open applications likes notepad?

Thanks.

Comment: You can open application like notepad. Check this out  https://windowsloop.com/open-webpage-on-schedule-task-scheduler/ instead of chrome you can give the notepad.exe location

Comment: Have you granted "User A" "log on as batch" rights in the local security policy? When you run a task as a user without the user logged in, they are running as a batch session, not an interactive session. There is a difference.

Comment: @TimJarosz yes, I give to A the permissions to log on as batch, in fact when I open task manager, I can see the application running and with user A. So the task works opening my application. Also I can send command to my service, like "Hello" and I get response.

Comment: @CanberkSahin you link talks about how to use an scheduler task to open a web page (or notepad or any other application). But in my case i want to open my service application. This can do it with no problems. The problem is that my service application can open the notepad if it is opening manually but it can't open it if it is run with a scheduled task that is set to open without need the user is logged on.

Comment: may be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913172/create-process-in-user-session-from-service